# Getting directory structure in windows mobile

Tags: c++, windows-mobile

Is there a way to get the directory structure in windows mobile in C++?

There is no folder browse dialog in MFC or in win32 for the windows mobile so I searched for a way to get the directory structure inside the code and even this seems difficult to find. These operations are very easy to perform in .NET compact framework but the application I am working on is a C++ application.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to call `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile`. If you want to do it remotely (from a desktop computer connected to the mobile device) you can use `CeFindFirstFile` and `CeFindNextFile` instead.